Sources on how Chess Engines Influenced Chess
I wonder if you know about any examples where people talk about how they are training with Chess Engines and what potentially has changed the "meta" in Chess.
Example of what I mean would be:

Quotes from GMs or people in the field about the influence of AI
Training regimes of GMs

It might be the case that Chess stood up pretty well and this isn't a topic at all, but I wonder if there's anything I missed out on.

GM Matthew Sadler extensively writes and talks about engines in all parts of chess. The book "Game Changer" by Matthew Sadler and Natasha Regan is probably the highest regarded book on how an engine influenced human play.
